# Troubling Including libcurl in Eclipse C++ Project

Tags: c++, eclipse, curl, linker, libcurl

Hi I am having trouble configuring an Eclipse C++ (32bit) project to use libcurl. I am using MinGW. I am on a 64bit windows OS. I have done the following so far:

- Add libcurl.lib to the Library to the project's Libraries
- Add the path of libcurl.lib to the Library Paths
- Add the path to the curl header files to the Includes section
- In my source file, I included "curl/curl.h"

However, I am seeing the following message:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\lib" "-LC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\dlls" "-LC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\bin" -o TestLibCurl.exe "src\\TestLibCurl.o" "-lC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\lib\\libcurl.lib" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\projectsrc\Network\curl-7.34.0-win32\lib\libcurl.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*UPDATE*

Below is the sample source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     cout << "test" <<< endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Below is a screenshot of where I added the include path and the library file:

[image]

For your reference, I have uploaded my sample C++ eclipse project to dropbox here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jowlkz6qypqe9g/TestingLibCurl.zip

The project file includes main.cpp, the libcurl.lib file, the libcurl header files, and the eclipse project setting files (.cproject, .project, .settings)

Comment: I'm assuming when you look at C:\projectsrc\Network\curl-7.34.0-win32\lib\ you see the library there?  Could you post your sample code?

Comment: Hi. Yes that is correct. I added the library "libcurl.lib" under the Libraries and added the include path to the curl directory under Includes in the project settings. The sample code can be seen above in the original post. It is including the curl header file (unmodified) but it still displays some kind of link error message.

Comment: @anoneironaut - i updated my original post to include the source code

Comment: It feels like a 64bit/32bit problem.  But you said everything was 32 bit.  Can you link in other libraries?  Maybe try to link a random library and see if that works for you.

Comment: The odd thing is that I am on the same Windows OS (64 bit) and I am using the same library file and source code, but it works in the CodeBlocks IDE.

Comment: Is the way that I am adding a library file (libcurl.lib) incorrect? Do I need to add a flag/option in order for it to work?

Comment: Can I see your eclipse configuration for the curl library?  Where do you add it as a link target?

Comment: Hi anoneironaut - sure. I have uploaded my sample c++ eclipse project to dropbox here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jowlkz6qypqe9g/TestingLibCurl.zip

Comment: The project includes main.cpp, the libcurl.lib file, the libcurl header files, and the eclipse project setting files (.cproject, .project, .settings)

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi anoneironaut, was the sample project able to work for you?